# Reading excel file stored in hdfs using java

Tags: hadoop, hive, apache-poi, hdfs, user-defined-functions

I am writing a UDF for Hive using Java. I have to read excel files stored in hdfs and do some processing using udf. I am using poi library for processing.

When we read from hdfs we get  FSDataInputStream but When we create Workbook using POI it needs InputStream Object.
Though code is not giving error at compile time.

```
FSDataInputStream stream = hdfs.open(new Path(inputFile));
Workbook workbook= new XSSFWorkbook(stream);
```

But When I create temporary function I get:

> Execution Error, return code -101 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FunctionTask. org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Workbook

Comment: Do you get any errorstack ? Please paste that as well .

Comment: No error stack. This was the error I got when I tried create temp function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you didn't add all dependent jars. You need to either build your jar with dependency or add all dependent jars one by one.

Command: hive> add myjar.jar

Comment: In the maven dependencies(pom file) , I have specified all poi dependencies.

Comment: Yes, but by default, when you are using maven to create jar it will not add dependent jars. Only classes you have created. Look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574594/how-can-i-create-an-executable-jar-with-dependencies-using-maven

Comment: Yes, as said in link I have provided above you need to build jar with dependency. Then add this jar to hive, like have you done before and then error should not appear anymore.

Comment: After which tag do I need to write this set of properties? It is giving error  in  pom xml

Comment: Can you please tell @Luk

Comment: I have removed main class since in Hive UDF we don't have any main class.Now its working. Thanks @Luk